# Simple inheritance question

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

Suppose I have the following hierarchy:

```
class A  
{  
 public:  
 A()   
 private:  
 int aa;  
}

class B: public A  
{  
 public:  
 B()   
 private:  
 int bb;  
}

class D: public B  
{  
 public:  
 D()   
 private:  
 int dd;  
}
```

When I type in the following code in my main:

```
D dobj;
std::cout<<"Address of D object: "<<&dobj<<std::endl;

A aobj = static_cast<A>(dobj);
A* aptr = static_cast<A*>(&dobj);

std::cout<<"Address of D object: "<<&dobj<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Address of aptr object: "<<&aptr<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Address of A object: "<<&aobj<<std::endl;
```

The output of which is:

```
Address of dobj object: 0012FF0C
Address of dobj object: 0012FF0C
Address of aptr object: 0012FF18
Address of aobj object: 0012FF14
```

Why is the address of aptr and aobj different ?? Aren't they supposed to be the same ??

And why is the address of dobj and aptr different ?? Aren't they supposed to be same as well ??

I am compiling on windows using VC++.

Thanks,
De Costo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why are `aptr` and `&aobj` different?

First, you are printing out the wrong pointer:  `&aptr` is "the address of `aptr`," not "the address of the object to which `aptr` points."  You need to print just `aptr` to print "the address of the object to which `aptr` points," which is presumably what you really want to do.

`aptr` is a pointer to the `A` part of `dobj`.  `aobj` is a *copy* of the `A` part of `dobj`.

`aptr` and `&aobj` are different because they are the addresses of different objects.

Comment: @de costo:  First, the cast is unnecessary:  you can implicitly convert a `D*` to an `A*`, so you can just say `aptr = dptr;`.  These pointers may have the same value:  `aptr` will point to the `A` base class part of the `D` object.  If the `A` base class part is located at the beginning of the `D` object, then `aptr` will be the same as `dptr`.

Comment: My bad !! Thanks for pointing out, However if I cast it to a pointer of B as in:  B* bptr = static_cast<B*>(&dobj); The address of aptr and bptr are the same. If bptr points to the B part of the D object, and since B base class is not located at beginning of D object, Should'nt aptr and bptr be different ??

Comment: @de costo:  Chances are, the `B` class is laid out in memory like `[A base class][bb member]` and the `D` class is laid out in memory like `[B base class][dd member]`.  This way, given `D x;`, all three of the following will give the same address:  (1) `&x`, (2) `static_cast<B*>(x)`, and (3) `static_cast<A*>(x)`.  If you are compiling using Visual C++ (or on most other compilers), then in a single-inheritance hierarchy like you show, the base class should always be located at the beginning of a derived class (it ends up being cheaper to cast up and down the inheritance hierarchy that way).

Comment: Is there any way I could find out the way they are laid out in memory ?? I know it is different in different OS's but is there any general format for such a memory organization ??